# Can we use azure functions for an incoming XML post

Tags: function, azure

I am new to azure and trying to learn about azure functions, I implemented a HTTP Trigger function where it receives Json as a payload and converts the body content Json to a string and then using Json deserializer into a POCO object  and puts the object into a output queue using outputBinding.
I would like to know
1) Can we have an xml post req to our azure function.
2) If so, I would like send the body content(XML) as an xml (I dont want xml to be converted to string) to the output Queue.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since functions are merely HTTP listeners which accept HTTP POSTs, you can most certainly accept a POST containing XML content. I'm not sure what you're after by trying to avoid converting XML to a string, since the input to the function is a stream of bytes representing an HTTP request - a string.

I'm not sure why you'd want to introduce the overhead of loading into an XML document, but here is an example of how you could do it:

```
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string body = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();    
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml(body);
}
```